# Write jquery library function into typescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, typescript

I have written a directive by using typescript. The code is look like this.

```
'use strict';

module App.Directives {

    interface IPageModal extends ng.IDirective {
    }

    interface IPageModalScope extends ng.IScope {
        //modal: any;
    }

    class PageModal implements IPageModal {
        static directiveId: string = 'pageModal';
        restrict: string = "A";

        constructor(private $parse: IPageModalScope) {
        }

        link = (scope: IPageModalScope, element, attrs) => {

            element.on('click', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                var options = {
                    backdrop: 'static',
                    keyboard: false
                };
                event.openModal = function () {
                    $('#' + attrs['targetModal']).modal(options);//error
                };
                event.showModal = function () {
                    $('#' + attrs['targetModal']).modal('show');//error
                };
                event.closeModal = function () {
                    $('#' + attrs['targetModal']).modal('hide');//error
                };
                var fn = this.$parse(attrs['pageModal']);
                fn(scope, { $event: event });
            });
        }
    }

    //References angular app
    app.directive(PageModal.directiveId, ['$parse', ($parse) => new PageModal($parse)]);
}
```

When I call jquery bootstrap .modal function then error occurring. How can i call this function below

> $('#' + attrs['targetModal']).modal('hide'); //error line of code

Answer (score 1):

> jquery bootstrap .modal function then error occurring

If its a compile time error you need a *type definition*. More : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/ambient/d.ts.html

## Fix

A quick one in `foo.d.ts`:

```
interface JQuery {
  modal: any;
}
```

Comment: How can i call this line $('#' + attrs['targetModal']).modal('hide');

Comment: With `jquery.d.ts` and the `foo.d.ts` that I provided : your code `$('#' + attrs['targetModal']).modal('hide');` will compile just fine

Comment: .modal is the function of twitter bootstrap

Comment: I have solved from here https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/bootstrap/bootstrap.d.ts